# python aiortc datachannel has a great latency

Tags: python, webrtc, aiortc

## Demo

https://github.com/tsonglew/aiortc-datachannel-delay

run `python main.py` to start the server, then visit `localhost:8080` with a web browser

## Problem

I'm trying to process the video frames from video track, and send back the result with datachannel.

the result is replaced with `time.time()` in the above demo repo as following:

```py
self.channel.send(
      json.dumps({"now": time.time() * 1000})
)
```

the `<client receive from datachannel time> - <datachennl.send() time>` is considered as delay, and are `console.log`ed with code:

```js
ch.addEventListener("message", function (evt) {
    console.log(Date.now() - JSON.parse(evt.data).now);
});
```

## Output

[image]

as illustrated in the sreenshot, the delay is growing, but video and audio are fluent.

How can I get rid of the growing delay? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `RTCDataChannel.send` in `aiortc` do not send SCTP data chunks immediately. As a workaround, flushing outbound data queue and transmitting data explicitly may help.

```py
self.channel.send(json.dumps({"now": time.time() * 1000}))
await self.channel._RTCDataChannel__transport._data_channel_flush()
await self.channel._RTCDataChannel__transport._transmit()
```

for more details: https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/issues/547